# How to merge and test pr locally through jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to perform the below tasks using jenkins

1. User commits the code in its feature branch ( Github )
2. Users pushes the code and create the Pull request
3. Jenkins task should invoke and should first merge the Pull Request locally with develop branch, then it should build the develop branch and run test on it locally.
4. Once the test passes on the develop branch jenkins returns github with green signal to perform actual merge.

I am using Github pull request builder plugin
I am not able to merge and test the pull request locally using Jenkins. Please suggest some solution to perform the above tasks.
I have also followed this [url](https://christiangalsterer.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/continuous-integration-for-pull-requests-with-jenkins-and-stash/) but this is performing for stash.
Thanks

Comment: Please post the error stacktrace , that you face while running the pull request and merge job.

Comment: There is no stack trace. I need a proper way for this